# display manager name and count of employees reporting him in employees table

Tags: oracle

I want to display manager_name and count of employees reporting him in employees table.I want to sort the data based on count IE maximum employees reporting to a manager should come first.

I tried to write self join but i could not get the out put .

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           MANAGER_ID     SALARY HIRE_DATE

---

```
    198 Donald                      124       2600 21-JUN-99
    199 Douglas                     124       2600 13-JAN-00
    200 Jennifer                    101       4400 17-SEP-87
    201 Michael                     100      13000 17-FEB-96
    202 Pat                         201       6000 17-AUG-97
    203 Susan                       101       6500 07-JUN-94
    204 Hermann                     101      10000 07-JUN-94
    205 Shelley                     101      12000 07-JUN-94
    206 William                     205       8300 07-JUN-94
    100 Steven                               24000 17-JUN-87
    101 Neena                       100      17000 21-SEP-89
```

the table name is employees and i want to see names also

Comment: Please add the table creation statements.

Comment: Plz share some sample data, schema design, and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function **COUNT** and **ORDER BY** clause
You didn't mention the table name assuming the table name as EMPLOYEES, below query would help you.

```
SELECT MANAGER_ID, COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) as EMP_COUNT 
  FROM EMPLOYEES  
 GROUP BY MANAGER_ID 
 ORDER BY EMP_COUNT DESC;
```

Here EMP_COUNT is the column alias name.If you don't want any column alias you can simply use the query below.

```
SELECT MANAGER_ID, COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) 
  FROM EMPLOYEES 
 GROUP BY MANAGER_ID 
 ORDER BY COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) DESC;
```

If you want to sort by ascending order instead of DESC you can use ASC.

Comment: If you could post some detailed info like table schema it would be more easier.

Comment: The table schema which you specified contains only the manager_id. If you want to display names you can use join or nested sql queries using the retrieved manager id.Post the details of the table which contains manager name. you will have a table with mapping for manager_id and manager_name,post the schema of that table.

Answer (score 0):

We can get this output using an analytical function:

```
SELECT E.EMPID,E.EMPNAME as "Manager Name",M.EMPNAME AS "Employee Name",count(*) over(partition by e.empid) reportee_count
 from empmgid m,empmgid e where M.MAGID=e.EMPID order by reportee_count desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please employ the following SQL-Query:

```
SELECT
    e.empno,
    e.ename,
    e1.empcnt
FROM
    emp e,
    (
        SELECT
            mgr,
            COUNT(*) empcnt
        FROM
            emp
        GROUP BY
            mgr
    ) e1
WHERE
    e.empno = e1.mgr;
```

Comment: To make your answer more useful to future readers please explain what your statement is doing, what you've changed etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Restricting which manager is having two employees working under them
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT E1.* FROM
(
SELECT E1.EMPNO,E1.ENAME AS EMPLOYE,
M1.ENAME AS MANAGERS,
COUNT(*)
OVER
(
PARTITION BY E1.EMPNO
) EMPCNT
FROM EMP E1,EMP M1
WHERE M1.MGR=E1.EMPNO
) E1
WHERE EMPCNT = 2;
```

Comment: Please don't write text in all caps (specifically the comment) - it's considered shouting on the internet

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select count(distinct manager_id) from employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(distinct manager_id) from employees;

Ans:
COUNT(DISTINCTMANAGER_ID)
18

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).